# How do I include window.onresize to make divs responsive within container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to redefine the width of the container using window.onresize or something similar. Currently, the .bouncer objects are not responsive to the browser window size. Each time I place window.onresize within the code, it completely stops the movement of 'bouncer."

```
window.onresize = 
  function hitLR(el, bounding) {
    console.log($(el).data('vx'), $(el).data('vy'))
    if (el.offsetLeft <= 0 && $(el).data('vx') < 0) {
        console.log('LEFT');
        $(el).data('vx', -1 * $(el).data('vx'))
    }
    if ((el.offsetLeft + el.offsetWidth) >= bounding.offsetWidth) {
        console.log('RIGHT');
        $(el).data('vx',  -1 * $(el).data('vx'));
    }
    if (el.offsetTop <= 0 && $(el).data('vy') < 0) {
        console.log('TOP');
        $(el).data('vy', -1 * $(el).data('vy'));
    }
    if ((el.offsetTop + el.offsetHeight) >= bounding.offsetHeight) {
        console.log('BOTTOM');
        $(el).data('vy', -1 * $(el).data('vy'));
    }
}


function mover(el, bounding) {
    hitLR(el, bounding);
    el.style.left = el.offsetLeft + $(el).data('vx') + 'px';
    el.style.top = el.offsetTop + $(el).data('vy') + 'px';

}

setInterval(function() {
    $('.bouncer').each(function(){
        mover(this, $('.bouncyHouse')[0]);
    });
}, 50);



$(document).bind('beforeReveal.facebox', function() {
    var height = $(window).height() - 100;
    $('#facebox .content').css('height', height + 'px');
    $('#facebox').css('top', ($(window).scrollTop() + 10) + 'px');
});
```

Comment: My apologies! Mixed it with $(window).resize(). You can refer to following [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/9bzu33r2/) for reference.